# YouTubePlayerView reloads the video on screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I launch a youtube video from my app using the following activity.
When the activity is launched, youtube video is played. But when I change the orientation of the screen, the video is not resuming but started from the beginning.
What's the issue here?

```
package com.example.blahblah;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class YTPlayActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {


       static private String yt_sk;
       static private final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "my-api-key";

       @Override

       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

              setContentView(R.layout.yt_player);
              Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
             yt_sk = extras.getString("yt_sk");

              YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)
findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

           youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

          }

         @Override

         public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
YouTubeInitializationResult error) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Oh no! "+error.toString(),
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }
       @Override

       public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
boolean wasRestored) {

              player.loadVideo(yt_sk);

       }



}
```

Comment: If you rotate your screen, your Activity is re-created. maybe you have to listen to the `OnConfigurationChanged` event and check, if video is playing at the moment. if yes, save current timecode and init video with saved timecode... at least i would check that (it`s a guess in the dark)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Added the configChanges in the AndroidManifest file and it worked.

Eg:

```
 <activity android:label=Activity Name" 
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
  android:name="com.example.blahblah">
```

Comment: Typically you should try to avoid doing this, as the Android documentation calls it a "last resort", but if you're doing this on an activity that is JUST a YouTubePlayerView it shouldn't be harmful :)

Comment: It works but keep on using the portrait xml file instead of switching to the landscape file

Comment: @RiotGoesWoof my activity does not only have YouTubePlayerView. In this case what is suggested approach? I have list view under player view as well.